# Is there a better way to write this regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to pull the weather from the weather network.  This code gives it to me, but it looks pretty long, and returns two values in the array (that's why I need to return $output[1] and not $output[0]), when I only want it to return one.  Any ideas?

```
$url=file_get_contents("http://www.theweathernetwork.com/weather/cans0057?ref=homecity");

preg_match('/<div id="obs_conds" class="hslice">.*?<img.*?alt="(.*?)".*?<\/div>/s',$url,$output);

print_r($output[1]);
```

Comment: Don't regex HTML - Parse it. HTML is not Regular.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: The Weather Channel also provides the weather data as RSS Feed which is much easier to parse: `echo simplexml_load_file('http://rss.theweathernetwork.com/weather/cans0057')->channel->item[0]->description;`

Comment: Your code was my best option.  Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's great. Maybe you can make shortcut from it

```
preg_match('/class="hslice">.*?<img.*?alt="(.*?)"/s',$url,$output);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works just as well. :)  Do you know why I'm getting two values in my array and not one?

Comment: because [0] has ALWAYS whole "search for" matched value

Answer (score 0):

I believe preg_matches returns the whole match in the the first element of the array $output[1] and $output[1] the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Regarding the regex optimization, I guess you're trying to pull everything inside `<div id="obs_conds" class="hslice">`, if that is the case I would try to do a dom search instead.

On the other hand maybe the best solution is to contact the site and set a webservice client. It seems to me that they do have the infrastucture for that.